Old wallet, stuck transaction
I have an old wallet from about 10 years ago that I found in Bitcoin Core. I tried sending the balance to a different wallet I use but the transaction just sat as pending. Looking for help on what to do.
Here's what happened:

Upgraded to latest Bitcoin Core v27, allowed blockchain to fully sync
Created tx to send btc from old wallet to new wallet (went with recommended fees)
Tx sat for couple of days unconfirmed so I went looking for help on how to increase fees
Using "increase fees" option in Core failed, so tried something I found in a thread using -walletbroadcast=0
Was able to abandon tx successfully in Core/old wallet
Created new transaction with 2x fees just to see if that helped but tx still shows pending (Core says in mem pool, but unconfirmed)
mempool.space shows old wallet address balance as 0, but still shows original tx as pending in new wallet

Looking for any ideas / help on what to do to transfer my btc to my new wallet

What feerate (satoshi per vbyte) are you using?

OK, was able to fix by creating a new tx with a higher fee (6090 sat) and then abandoning that new tx. When I did that, the option to increase the fee of the original tx worked! So all good and the old tx finally cleared.
